# "How to Ask in Private Beta" displayed every time

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta, asking-questions

Since yesterday I get the explanation on "How to Ask in Private Beta" every single time I click on Ask Question on a private beta site. This happens on Drupal.SE and Skeptics.SE and their meta sites.

I have already asked quite some questions there, is it really intended that this notification is displayed every single time?  Shouldn't it only be shown for the first question?

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing it every time - looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops -- this was a newbie mistake by me. Now fixed. You should only get it on the first question now as intended.