# Remove/Re-think "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" page on communities no longer in beta

Tags: feature-request, help-center, graduating-sites

Please review the help page at `/help/how-to-ask-beta` for all communities that are no longer in beta status.  This will lead to reader confusion.  I think the right panel link (which is available from /help/asking) should be given new text ...if the destination page is going to be kept at all.

> [image]

Related:

- From 2017: [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/352329)

Not Related:

- From 2011: ["How to Ask in Private Beta" displayed every time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81563/352329)
- From 2011: [Please link “How to Ask in Private Beta” on private beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102839/352329)